# Disnake | The message is not displayed after selecting an option in the selection menu

Tags: python, discord, disnake

An ephemeral message is not displayed after selecting an option from the Select-Menu

Source-Code:

```
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands
from disnake.ui import View, Select

class RulesCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def rules(self, ctx):
        embed = disnake.Embed(
            title="Rules",
            description="Please follow the rules below:",
            color=disnake.Color.blue()
        )

        embed.add_field(name="Rule 1", value="The first rule")
        embed.add_field(name="Rule 2", value="The second Rule")
        embed.add_field(name="Rule 3", value="The third rule")

        options = [
            disnake.SelectOption(label="Option 1", description="The first option"),
            disnake.SelectOption(label="Option 2", description="The second option"),
            disnake.SelectOption(label="Option 3", description="The third option")
        ]

        select = disnake.ui.Select(
            placeholder="Select an option",
            options=options,
            custom_id="select" 
        )

        view = disnake.ui.View()
        view.add_item(select)

        await ctx.send(embed=embed, view=view)

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_select_option(self, interaction: disnake.MessageInteraction):
        if interaction.component.custom_id == "select":
            selected_option = interaction.component.selected_options[0]
            await interaction.response.send_message(f"You have chosen: {selected_option.label}")
            await interaction.message.edit(view=None)


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(RulesCog(bot))
```

In theory, an ephemeral message should be displayed after selecting the option, but discord writes "Interaction error".